# php filtragem de dados e count

Tags: php

Boas é o seguinte eu tenho uma app web onde gero gráficos, porem gostava de filtrar dados e fazer coutagens, tenho so dados numa bd, pelo que ja exportei e para evitar q app fique lenta estava a pensar em ler do csv  mas preciso de filtra os dados alguem sabe como posso fazer ex:

csv

```
Nome, profissão, Idade,Sexo ,Nacionalidade , quantidade
jose , trolha,10,M,nacional,10
jose , trolha,10,M,nacional,10
jose , trolhaassda1,10,M,nacional,10
jose , trolha1dsds,10,M,nacional,10
jose , trolh1111,10,M,nacional,10
jose , trolhadasdas,10,M,nacional,10
```

queria que aparece-se so o trolha. é possivel

output 
Nome, profissão, Idade,Sexo ,Nacionalidade , quantidade
jose , trolha,10,M,nacional,10
jose , trolha,10,M,nacional,10

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais performática de se fazer isso seria usando um banco de dados e filtrando os dados que você precisa.

No caso ao se utilizar de um arquivo é possível utilizar uma regex para extrair os dados que você precisa ou ler o arquivo inteiro e utilizar a função strpos do PHP.

Ex. em MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela_csv WHERE profissao LIKE '%trolha%';
```

Ex. em PHP utilizando RegEx:

```
$regex = "(.*?)\ ,\ (.*?)trolha(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)\n";
preg_match_all($regex, $csvContent, $matches);
```

Comment: e da para manter o header?

Comment: Sim, é possível manter o header já que você vai apenas formatar a saída das informações